# How to modify IEnumerable with LINQ to avoid foreach loop?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Can the following be done in LINQ as a one-liner, without using a for-loop?

```
IEnumerable<MyObj> MyList = EF.GetList(etc);
foreach (var row in MyList)
{
    row.uploadedAt = MyUtils.ConvertToLocalTime(row.uploadedAtUTC, clientTimezone);
}
//return MyList, which now has both dates in LocalTime and UTC
```

Comment: Attached duplicate has a couple of solution, but iterating using `foreach` seems to the cleanest way. Btw, there is no magic in `Linq`, it's still using looping under the hood

Comment: There's also LINQ method `ForEach`, which does exactly what it seems to do :) Also there is [asynchronous version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.foreachasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) `ForEachAsync`

Comment: @MichalTurczyn Is `ForEach` in LINQ? I am aware of no such method.

Comment: @mjwills you are right. Not LINQ,  List<T> has ForEach method. `MyList.ToList().ForEach(x=>...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reassign the list, ideally without mutating anything. This would be more consistent with the [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) mindset of LINQ.

```
IEnumerable<MyObj> myList1 = EF.GetList(etc);
IEnumerable<MyObj> myList2 = myList1.Select( x => 
        new MyObj 
        {
            uploadedAt = MyUtils.ConvertToLocalTime(x.uploadedAtUTC, x.clientTimezone),
            anyOtherFields = x.anyOtherFields
        }
    ).ToList();
```

If constructing a `MyObj` is complicated and/or you really need to mutate it, you can also do this:

```
IEnumerable<MyObj> myList = EF.GetList(etc);
myList = myList.Select( x => {
        x.uploadedAt = MyUtils.ConvertToLocalTime(x.uploadedAtUTC, x.clientTimezone);
        return x;
    }).ToList();
```

But if you're going to do it that way, you may as well use the `for` loop.

Comment: your second answer is what i tried to do myself, but was stuck with returning the whole object (return x in your answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to given answers, there's `List<T>` method ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netcore-3.1)) that mimics `foreach` loop:

```
EF.GetList(etc).ToList()
    .ForEach(row => row.uploadedAt = MyUtils.ConvertToLocalTime(row.uploadedAtUTC, clientTimezone));
```

But I don't see any advantage of simplifying things, that are already simple enough.

IMO, too much simplification leads to maintanance horror and reduces readability :)

Comment: LINQ does not have a `ForEach`. It's a method of the `List<T>` class.

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks, good catch :) corrected that.